# Jquery slidetoggle was working now not

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
    <div class="news">

 <p>   
  summary here<a href="#">more</a>
 </p>
<div class="more">
 <p>
  More News
 </p>
</div>
```

with the following jQuery

```
    $('.news a').click(function(event){
 //alert('.news');
 $(this).nextAll('.more').slideToggle();
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

For some reason it has stopped working, any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) finds siblings only, but you're inside a `<p>` now...so you need to go up one level:

```
$('.news a').click(function(event){
  $(this).parent().nextAll('.more').slideToggle();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```